# How one-sided black windows work?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

I have a main doubt here.
I've heard that just a thin layer of coating is sprayed on one side of the glass due to which there are minute gaps between the molecules through which light passes.

But the same should happen on both sides, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: It does happen in both sides, the reason it works is because one room is really darker than the other, so the reflected light is more intense than the light coming from the darker side (and vice versa)

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams has it right, and should make that an answer. Anecdotally, I had a friend who was in a (high school?) play version of Grease, and they had to have the lights in the car up high enough to make the heat they generated uncomfortable in order to overpower reflections from outside stage lights.